# How to find Docker REST API URI for Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, docker, centos

I am running Jenkins on a CentOS machine. I have a job that pulls a Github repo and builds a Docker image using the Docker plugin for Jenkins. When I try running the job I get the error:

```
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
java.lang.NullPointerException: uri was not specified
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:204)
    at com.github.dockerjava.core.DockerClientConfig$DockerClientConfigBuilder.withUri(DockerClientConfig.java:406)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.dockerbuildstep.DockerBuilder$DescriptorImpl.createDockerClient(DockerBuilder.java:120)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.dockerbuildstep.DockerBuilder$DescriptorImpl.getDockerClient(DockerBuilder.java:204)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.dockerbuildstep.DockerBuilder.perform(DockerBuilder.java:68)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:205)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:162)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1720)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Build step 'Execute Docker command' marked build as failure
```

How do I find this URI? When I run `sudo netstat -tunlp` I don't see docker anywhere. Furthermore, [this page](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api/) mentions that the Docker daemon listens on `unix:///var/run/docker.sock`. How do I resolve this?

This is my Dockerfile, for reference:

```
FROM ubuntu:15.04

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y  software-properties-common && \
    add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java -y && \
    apt-get update && \
    echo oracle-java7-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true\
 | /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections && \
    apt-get install -y oracle-java8-installer && \
    apt-get clean

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get -y install openjdk-8-jdk && \
    apt-get -y install sudo && \
    apt-get -y install curl && \
    apt-get -y install jq && \
    apt-get clean

# Add our Java code. Use COPY command so that jar file stays compressed.
COPY myJavaApp.jar myJavaApp.jar

# Add the shell script
ADD script.sh .

# Add env info file
ADD envInfo .

# Set permissions for shell script and execute it, generating the application.properties file within the current Docker image layer.
RUN sudo chmod 755 script.sh && sudo ./script.sh

EXPOSE 8080  

# Upon container startup, execute the JAR with the appropriate parameters
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Dspring.profiles.active=sierra", \
            "-Dspring.config.location='file:application.properties'", \
            "-jar", "myJavaApp.jar", "--debug", \
            "--spring.config.location=file:application.properties"]
```

Comment: Is docker installed on your jenkins slave?

Comment: I have installed [this Docker package](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Docker+build+step+plugin) on Jenkins. Also, I have Docker running on my CentOS machine but I am using the Docker plugin for Jenkins instead because I can't connect to the Docker daemon using Jenkins

Comment: can you fire a curl request to unix:///var/run/docker.sock on the instance and   check whether you get any response

Comment: try `curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http:/images/json`

Comment: When I try that I get `curl: option --unix-socket: is unknown` because my version of cURL on CentOS is  7.29.0 whereas the cURL 7.40 or later versions have support for the `--unix-socket` flag. I think version 7.29.0 is the latest stable build for CentOS.

Comment: welcome to docker world, you dont need the software on the host :D try `docker run -ti -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock nathanleclaire/curl sh` and then curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http:/images/json

Comment: I ran the commands and was able to get my images in JSON format. How would this apply to my Jenkins job though?

Comment: Atleast this confirms docker remote api is running, the issue must be with the plugin config. Can you confirm which plugin you are using?

Comment: [This](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Docker+build+step+plugin) is the plugin I am using.

Comment: The issue exposed is not related with Docker but with java. The same java program would fail even if out of Docker. If I understand this error is encountered during a docker build, isn't it? If so, could you provide the Dockerfile please?

Comment: @Auzias added Dockerfile

Comment: It looks like your [copy/add usage is not coherent](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#add-or-copy), also absolute path are preferred for destinations. Could you provide the `docker run` command please. When does the error occur? On the build or the execution?

Comment: The error occurs during the docker build step in the Jenkins job. I know the Dockerfile works because I can build it locally just fine. I think the problem has to do with Jenkins not being able to communicate with Docker properly.